# QGIS3 Reprojetion all layers in the table of Content

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How can I reproject all layers

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() 
for layer in layers:
    name=layer.name()
    #Die Variable mypath ist anzupassen, das vorgestellte r kann beibehalten werden. Es ist 
    #für den gemischten Betrieb mit Linux- und Windows-PCs erforderlich
    mypath = r"/home/cirrusklaus/Downloads/tmp/shp/" +  name + ".shp"
    #if "Road" in name:
    for layer in layers:
      name=layer.name()
      output_layer = mypath
      #Code for reprojecting all layers of the toc??
      #print("The job is done!")
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: What happened when you ran the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for vector and raster data on disk (not WMS etc):

```py
import os
out_folder = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/reprojected/"
out_crs = "EPSG:32610"

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(out_crs)
    
    if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer): #If it is a vector layer
        output = os.path.join(out_folder, f"{layer.name()}_reprojected.shp")
        processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':layer,'TARGET_CRS':crs,
          'OUTPUT':output})
    
    elif isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer): #Or a raster
        output = os.path.join(out_folder, f"{layer.name()}_reprojected.tif")
        processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", {'INPUT':layer,
        'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':crs,'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,
        'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=LZW','DATA_TYPE':0,
        'TARGET_EXTENT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,
        'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':output})

print("Done")
```

Comment: This code-snippet is greatly appreciated. What is the codeline for checking that th output  path exists?

Comment: [`os.path.exists`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-exists-method/)